# Adjusting resolution of Outlook 2016 mail signature images from 4K desktop for lower resolutions desktops

Tags: css, image, email, html-table, html-email

After days of struggle I'm posting question, I'm trying to adjust resolution of Outlook 2016 mail signature images from 4K desktop mail signature for lower resolutions desktops like 2560 x 1440.

Mail signature in Outlook is gnereated via my own signature generator, in other mail clients like Thunderbird, Roundcube this code worked with Codebase64 img encoding (I aplied the base64 code for signature and everything worked fine), for Outlook 2016/2019 I'm generating web page with this html with direct links on server where are other files for user data input and php file for collecting input and generating web page signature, I'm using direct links here (so I can select all / copy paste signature form web page to Outlook), this is only a part of complete html for Outlook signature, mentioning only telephone, mail, website and pinner part:

```
<td style="  color:#000000;  text-decoration:none;  font-size:13px;  font-weight:normal; line-height:18px;  mso-line-height-rule:exactly;  padding-bottom:30px;  padding-top: 30px  ">


    <div style=" width: fit-content;  ">  

        <div id="tel_mail_web_tds" style=" white-space: nowrap;      padding-top: 10px;  ">  
        
        
        <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr style=" white-space: nowrap; ">     
        
        
            <td  style=" line-height:14px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; " >
            
                <!--[if !mso]>-->
                <style type="text/css">
                @media only screen and (max-width: 3840px) and (min-width: 2160px) 
                {
                    img {
                        width:12px !important;
                        height:12px !important;
                        }
                        
                    #div_mail_sig
                    {
                        width: 250px !important;
                        height: 150px !important;
                    }   
                        
                }
                @media only screen and (max-width: 1600px) 
                {
                    img {
                        width:12px !important;
                        height:12px !important;
                        }
                        
                    #div_mail_sig
                    {
                        width: 250px !important;
                        height: 150px !important;
                    }   
                }
                </style>                
            <!--<![endif]-->    
            
            <!-- conditional formating nije pomoglo-->  
            
                            
            <img id="myImage_tel" class="sig_img" style=" vertical-align:baseline;  " src="222TELEFON.png" width="12" height="12" alt="telefon"   >
            
            
            </td>
            
            <!--[if !mso]><!-->
            <td>
            <!--<![endif]-->   
             
            <!--[if mso]>   
            <td  style=" vertical-align:baseline; " >
            <![endif]-->
             
            <a id="telLink" href="" style=" white-space: nowrap; font-family:   sans-serif ; color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-size:13px;  font-weight:normal; line-height:18px;  padding-bottom:5px; color: #7b7979; "> <?php echo $djelatnik_tel;  ?>  </a>
            </td>   
            
            <td> <span width="40">      </span></td>   
            

            <td style=" line-height:16px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; " >
            <img style="vertical-align:baseline; " src="222PISMO.png" width="16" height="12" alt="e-mail" />
            </td>
            
            <!--[if !mso]><!-->
            <td>
            <!--<![endif]-->   
             
            <!--[if mso]>   
            <td  style=" vertical-align:baseline; " >
            <![endif]-->
                            
            <a id="mailtoLink" href="" style=" font-family:  sans-serif; color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-size:13px;  font-weight:normal; line-height:18px;  padding-bottom:5px;  color: #7b7979; ">  <?php echo $djelatnik_email;  ?> </a> 
            </td>
            
            <td> <span width="40">      <span></span></span></td>
            
            <td>
            <img style="vertical-align:baseline; " src="222GLOBUS.png" width="12" height="12" alt="globus" />
            </td>
            
            <!--[if !mso]><!-->
            <td>
            <!--<![endif]-->   
             
            <!--[if mso]>   
            <td  style=" vertical-align:baseline; " >
            <![endif]-->
            
            <a href="https://www.kbsplit.hr/" style=" font-family:  sans-serif; color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-size:13px; font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;  padding-bottom:5px;  color: #7b7979;   ">www.kbsplit.hr</a>
            </td>       
            
            
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

        </div>

        <br />

        <div style="margin-top:-10px;">
    
             <img style="vertical-align:baseline; " src="222PINNER.png" width="12" height="12" alt="pinner" />
            
            <a id="kbc_adresa" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Spin%C4%8Di%C4%87eva+ul.+1,+21000,+Split/@43.5037592,16.4579596,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x13355e1de14211af:0xd81e9e8e12de3e1b!8m2!3d43.5037592!4d16.4579596!16s%2Fg%2F11c5nz4_hb" style=" font-family:  sans-serif; color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;  padding-bottom:5px;  color: #7b7979; ">
            Spinčićeva 1, 21000 Split, Hrvatska</a> 
    
        </div>
    
    </div>
        
    
</td>
```

This HTMl is working when desktop computers with lower then 4K reslolutins like 2560 x 1440 are generating and receiving signature, when I generate web page with upper output my process is that users then Select All from web page /mail signature output except btn for selecting and then Copy that web page mail signature representation to Outlook : Options - Mail - Signature - signature editor and averything is fine except when 4K computer generates that web page and aplies like mentioned signature and sends mail to lower resolution computers , then logo and other  img tags get oversized and nothing helps to correct that.
Images that are 12 x 12 px in normal size on lower resolution get to 18 x 18 size....

I tried adjusting images to fit both both desktops but that deoesn't look well, I tried using html5 canvas for adjusting image resolutions, but i'm not knowledgeable about that and how to do that right, I tried to give encopasing table tag a fixed width, lower width so that logo doesn't come to other lower resolution side destop oversized, but couldn't manage to change table size, this doesnt get applied:
`<table id="div_mail_sig"  width="200" height ="150">`
I also tried @media only screen targeting so that images always stay 12 x 12 (#div_mail_sig is main div)but to no avail since Outlook is sensitive how we apply styles, meaning must be inline etc etc.

I am wondering is there any solution to this, thx in advance.

Nikola

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Windows is essentially print-based in its rendering engine. So it is not responsive. It will calculate everything as inches and fixed sizes. So you need to pick a size for your Outlook email (usually up to 600px) and base your images and layout off that.

Also it expects particular attributes, and for width in images that is the width attribute: `<img width="200"...>`. It cannot have "px" after the number or anything - just a number. You can use the style width for all other email clients like so: `<img width="200" style="width:100%;" ...>`.

As it is, without the width attribute, Outlook renders images according to their actual width.

Comment: My img tags in code above are without px notation, also this mine sentence was just for testing  :
"but couldn't manage to change table size, this doesnt get applied: <table id="div_mail_sig"  width="200" height ="150"> "

I dont mean to have table that is responsive or with fixed with because some employees names and departments names are too wide and I want to make it able for signature to output it as wide as necessary.

Problem is my signature from Outlook 2016 on 4K desktop sent via mail to some lower resolution desktop on which I get enlarged logo and icons, meaning all img tags ...